# StreamsException: No valid committed offset found for input topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two node Kafka cluster with replication factor two. My Kafka version is 0.10.2.0.

Previously my application was used 0.11.0.0 Kafka Streams API. This is changed 0.11.0.1 Kafka stream to fix [Kafka Streams application is throwing 'CommitFailedException' exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454998/kafka-streams-application-is-throwing-commitfailedexception-exceptions) as suggested at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5786 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5152

Following are ConsumerConfig values:

```
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [1.1.1.1:9092, 1.1.1.2:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.id = sample-app-0.0.1-27c65ef7-d07f-4619-96be-852f5772d73d-StreamThread-1-consumer
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = sample-app-0.0.1
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
internal.leave.group.on.close = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 2147483647
max.poll.records = 1000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

But one of my application is throwing below exception after running some time even though previously committed offsets are available. What would be the possible reason? Please explain.

```
017-12-04 12:03:25,410 ERROR c.e.s.c.f.k.s.r.f.SampleStreamsApp [sample-app-0.0.1-096850bc-5f18-4c59-b0c7-63ad00e08aa1-StreamThread-1] No valid committed offset found for input topic sampel (partition 0) and no valid reset policy configured. You need to set configuration parameter "auto.offset.reset" or specify a topic specific reset policy via KStreamBuilder#stream(StreamsConfig.AutoOffsetReset offsetReset, ...) or KStreamBuilder#table(StreamsConfig.AutoOffsetReset offsetReset, ...) org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: No valid committed offset found for input topic sample (partition 0) and no valid reset policy configured. You need to set configuration parameter "auto.offset.reset" or specify a topic specific reset policy via KStreamBuilder#stream(StreamsConfig.AutoOffsetReset offsetReset, ...) or KStreamBuilder#table(StreamsConfig.AutoOffsetReset offsetReset, ...)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.resetInvalidOffsets(StreamThread.java:567)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:538)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:490)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:480)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:457)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException: Undefined offset with no reset policy for partitions: [sample-0]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffsets(Fetcher.java:425)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.resetOffsetsIfNeeded(Fetcher.java:254)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1640)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1083)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:536)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Did you alter consumer `auto.offset.rest` policy to `"none"` ?

Comment: I did not configure anything for 'auto.offset.reset'. So by default `earliest` is considering.

Comment: That's weird. I "earliest" is configure, there should never be an `NoOffsetForPartitionException` exception. Can you share the log output of the consumer config (it's part of the Streams log).

Comment: updated above in my question

Comment: Hmmm... i see that the `group.id = ` is empty... that's weird. It should use the `application.id` as group.id... What `application.id` do you set?

Comment: Having said this: are you sure it's the correct consumer config? Note, Kafka Streams uses 2 consumers internally. It seems, you posted the config from the restore consumer that does not have a `group.id` assigned.

Comment: Yes Matthias, You are correct.I updated from restore consumer. After creating consumer client, consumer config values were updating in log.  Above values were replaced by these..

Comment: The config says `auto.offset.reset = earliest` -- thus it seems to be an issue in the consumer. It should never throw this exception. Can use reproduce this reliably? I would recommend to report this at the Kafka mailing list: https://kafka.apache.org/contact

Comment: As per Kafka documentation, enable.auto.commit would be `true`. But here the value is `false`. I try to set this to true in the consumer properties but this value is reverting back to false with  message `Unexpected user-specified consumer config: enable.auto.commit found. User setting (true) will be ignored and the Streams default setting (false) will be used` Is there any problem with my application?

Comment: No. Streams need to manage commits and thus we need to disable consumer auto committing and don't allow to enable it. That's by design. Note, Kafka Streams will call commit explicitly on the consumer and you don't need to worry about it.